# Android development

Tags: android

Does the Android Application Development comes under the J2ME programming or is it totally/partially different?

Please do let me know if anybody has a clear idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

J2ME and Android development use Java as their primary programming language, but application lifecycles, libraries, and a number of other aspects are completely different.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this tutorial](http://zeeshanakhter.com/2012/03/01/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-i/) is quite a good starting point.

If I were you, I'd definitely spend some time to [learn Unity3D and use it for Android development](http://vimaltuts.com/android-game-development/android-game-development-tutorial-sample-scene-unity-3d). Unity allows you to develop games with great graphics and solid collision and camera support rapidly.